# Twin sisters, who are we?

Tags: riddle

Twin sisters are always next to each other.
We see all but we can't see each other.
We are with you right now.
who are we?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is:

> eyes

We see all but we can't see each other:

> they literally see but cant each other

We are with you right now.

> except for unfortunate circunstances we all have 2 eyes

Comment: Right answer, since USer123 was bit quicker in few seconds, so marked that as answer.

Comment: i guessed it was about the time. but in my defense it took longer cause i wrote and explained more

Comment: Valid point....

Comment: My eyes aren't twins! Just saying. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterochromia_iridum

Comment: there are identical twins and fraternal twins  @Jakerobb

Comment: @lois6b fair point! :)

Comment: in spanish we have two different words (identical twins = gemelo and fraternal twins = mellizo) @jakerobb

Answer (score 10):

Another possible answer

> **front and rear cameras of a mobile device**.

We see all but we can't see each other.

> both camera's can see all, but can't see each other.

We are with you right now.

> almost everyone reading this have a mobile device with front and rear cams.

Comment: Pc ^^' and also, my phone has 2 back cameras and one front

Comment: @lois6b, then you got triplet sisters :D

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer -

> sun and moon

Twin sisters are always next to each other and can't see each other.

> sun comes in day and moon night.

Comment: sometimes you can see both at the same time

Comment: The only reason you can see the moon is that it is illuminated by the sun (i.e., that they can "see" each other). Indeed, the _only_ time that the sun and moon can't see each other is during a total lunar eclipse. (Also, the sun and moon aren't really twins -- one's a mass of self-fusing hydrogen; the other's a lump of rock.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby "the other's a lump of rock" - I assume that was a typo and you meant to write cheese?

Comment: @MD-Tech but both appear same size from earth.

Answer (score -3):

This puzzle refers to

> the human eyes, as they are always with each other. One eye can't see the other.